# Spark using multiple groupby in a single chain. How to avoid?

Tags: apache-spark

This is my second job using Spark and I was wondering if it was possible to avoid similar operations.

My scenario: I have a row table and I would like to pivot that table to have columns instead of rows. After that, I want to perform some aggregations to find out max values and return a new output.

I've wrote a code that is working and looks like:

```
df_inbound = df \
    .where(col("event_type").isin(['task.created', 'task.completed', 'task.canceled']))\
    .withColumn("event_type", regexp_replace(col("event_type"), "\.", "_")) \
    .groupBy(
        "event_data.task_sid",
        "task_attributes.call_sid") \
    .pivot("event_type") \
    .agg(first(to_timestamp("event_date"))) \
    .groupBy(
        "task_sid",         
        "call_sid") \
    .agg(
        mx("task_created").alias("task_created"),
        mx("task_completed").alias("task_completed"),
        mx("task_canceled").alias("task_canceled"),
    ) \
    .withColumn("call_ended", coalesce(col("task_canceled"), col("task_completed"))) \
    .select(        
        col("task_sid"),
        col("call_sid"),
        col("call_ended"),
        (col("call_ended").cast("long") - col("task_created").cast("long")).alias("total_call_time")
    )
```

Is possible to avoid multiple groupBy or aggr? Or is it a normal behaviour using Spark?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem statement from your example then I suppose instead of using `first()` as the pivot aggregation, simply using `max()` will beget you the desired result (helping you get rid of the extra `groupBy()` and `agg()`).